# Term for that you can only know truth or have knowledge within your own experience

Tags: epistemology, terminology

I have tried googling for the term but didn't find it. It's an -ism that refers to the fact that you can only know truth or have knowledge within your own experience.

It's different then moral relativism but beyond that I'm not sure.

Comment: Are you thinking of Berkeley's subjective idealism?

Comment: Perhaps, you are looking for perspectivalism? Or subjectivism?

Comment: Defining knowledge in such a way that you can only know truths is something totally different from the claim that you can have knowledge within your own experience. Experience, as optical illusions show, is different from truth. So probably your looking for two terms

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you mean "solipsism" :-

> "the philosophical idea that only one's own mind is sure to exist. As
>   an epistemological position, solipsism holds that knowledge of
>   anything outside one's own mind is unsure." -
>   [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solipsism)

A branch of [epistemology](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epistemology).

Comment: I'd agree with this answer (because it's what I would suggest), but am unsure what the OP is after. As a compromise, I'll upvote if it's the accepted answer.

Comment: YES THANK YOU SO MUCH. All caps to show excitement. I thought it was sedentism but thats an anthropological word.